# Is one-hour layover at Munich Airport enough time?

Tags: short-connections, lufthansa, muc

I am a USA citizen and will be flying from Athens, Greece to Munich, Germany with a layover in Munich for only about an hour before my connecting flight to San Francisco, USA.  Both flights will be with Lufthansa.

Will I have sufficient time to make my connecting flight?

Comment: http://www.munich-airport.de/en/general/faq/umsteigen/index.jsp